# How to refer from a not-yet-defined symbol from template class?

Tags: c++

I was thinking naively that inside template class I can refer to non-existing objects because they are not necessary before instantiation. But this doesn't work (compiler complains about non-declared NAME):

```
template<typename H>
class HandlerInfoClass
{
    std::string_view getName()
    {
        return NAME;
    }
};
```

Is there any way to overcome this without using the preprocessor or adding new template arguments (some of them may have types not allowed in this context)?

Comment: Perhaps a forward declaration is all you need? It's hard to tell without a more concrete example of how exactly you are going to use this class.

Comment: What *is* `NAME`?  A static data member of the template parameter `H` (in which case use `H::NAME`)?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and a full textual verbatim quote of all build messages directly here. Make sure that your understanding and expectations concerning `NAME` are obvious.

Comment: I.e. if you think you do not need the `NAME` during definition, then demonstrate when it is defined to be useable during use of this class.

Comment: Please, give an answer to this question, as a compiler does:
How should I consider the "NAME string", as it is not declared variable\ function\class etc..?
In C++ we could not refer to something which has no declaration.

Comment: @AwesomeMan Disagree. When You define template the compiler doesn't need to access referenced object because it doesn't generate any code. They are necessary at instantiation time, then code is generated.

Comment: @G.M. Good idea: when I put it into template parameter class (which is acceptable) and refer as H::NAME it works

Comment: NAME and other objects I wanted to refer this way are simple const char* or string_view strings or other trivial numercics.

Comment: @ardabro, Yes, you are right. I meant situation after all template instantiations, like the "final" code, which is ready to be translated into an assembly.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to refer to a non-existing object. A key property of a template function is that the output is always the same for given parameter(s). So it doesn't matter where you instantiate the template in your code, it will always call the same function for the same parameters.

What you are building looks like a trait class for a "handler". The correct way to write this would be to specialize the class for each different type like so:

```
template<typename H>
class HandlerInfoClass;

template<>
class HandlerInfoClass<HandlerType>
{
    static std::string_view getName()
    {
        return "HandlerType";
    }
};
```

If the string you are returning changes at runtime you shouldn't be building a traits class but add a `getName()` function to the object itself.

Comment: "So it doesn't matter where you instantiate the template in your code, it will always call the same function for the same parameters." Thanks for this sentence. Now I think I understood the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to G.M. I found a nice workaround: put "NAME" as static variable into type that is template parameter:

```
template<typename H>
class HandlerInfoClass
{
    std::string_view getName()
    {
        return H::NAME;
    }
};
```